# How to log INFO into one file and ERROR into another file using log4j in spring boot.

Tags: java

I have tried **application.properties**

```
logging.level.org.springframework.security= DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate= DEBUG
logging.file=D:/LogDemo/DemoDebug.log

logging.level.root= WARN
logging.file=D:/LogDemo/DemoWarn.log
```

---

*But log is appending only in the last file ( Here, demoinfo.log)*
If ERROR level is the last one , only log will appending only in the specified file.

And I have tried log4j2.xml also

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <appender name="DEBUG-LOG-FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender"> 
        <param name="file" value="D:/LogDemo/Debug.log"/> 
        <param name="append" value="true" /> 
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy"> 
      <!-- daily rollover -->
      <param name="FileNamePattern" value="Debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.zip"/> 
      <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history 
      <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="30"/> -->
    </rollingPolicy> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
        <!--<Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] %logger{35} - %msg%n</Pattern>-->
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %logger{35} - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter"> 
        <param name="LevelToMatch" value="debug"/> 
        <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/> 
        </filter>  
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/> 
  </appender> 

  <appender name="ERROR-LOG-FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender"> 
        <param name="file" value="D:/LogDemo/Error.log"/> 
        <param name="append" value="true" /> 
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy"> 
      <!-- daily rollover -->
      <param name="FileNamePattern" value="Error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.zip"/> 
      <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history 
      <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="30"/> -->
    </rollingPolicy> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <!--<Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] %logger{35} - %msg%n</Pattern>-->
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %logger{35} - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter"> 
                <param name="LevelToMatch" value="error" /> 
                <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/> 
        </filter> 
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter" /> 
  </appender> 

  <appender name="INFO-LOG-FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender"> 
        <param name="file" value="D:/LogDemo/Info.log"/> 
        <param name="append" value="true" /> 
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy"> 
      <!-- daily rollover -->
      <param name="FileNamePattern" value="Info.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.zip"/> 
      <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history 
      <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="30"/> -->
    </rollingPolicy> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <!--<Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] %logger{35} - %msg%n</Pattern>-->
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %logger{35} - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter"> 
                <param name="LevelToMatch" value="info" /> 
                <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/> 
        </filter> 
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter" /> 
  </appender> 

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %logger{35} - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter"> 
                <param name="LevelToMatch" value="debug" /> 
                <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/> 
        </filter> 
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter" /> 
  </appender> 

  <root> 
    <level value="debug" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="DEBUG-LOG-FILE" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="ERROR-LOG-FILE" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="INFO-LOG-FILE" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" /> 
  </root>
```

But I am not able to see any result related to log4j2.xml (Any congiguration needed ? )

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issues

1. Do you have `spring-boot-starter-logging` excluded and `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` added as a project's dependency?
2. Your `log4j2.xml` does not look valid - it's rather logback syntax and not log4j2's one.

To split log entries between different files - using `log4j2`, you need to:

Exclude logging and add log4j2 dependency:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Make changes in log4j2.xml. The idea is to filter out all other levels. Please notice, I grouped WARN and INFO into the same file

```xml
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">

    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p ${hostName} --- [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex
        </Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="File-DEBUG" fileName="logs/app-debug.log" filePattern="logs/app-debug-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz"
                     ignoreExceptions="false">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
                <ThresholdFilter level="DEBUG" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            </Filters>
        </RollingFile>

        <RollingFile name="File-INFO" fileName="logs/app-info.log" filePattern="logs/app-info-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz"
                     ignoreExceptions="false">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
                <ThresholdFilter level="WARN" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
                <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            </Filters>
        </RollingFile>


        <RollingFile name="File-ERROR" fileName="logs/app-error.log" filePattern="logs/app-error-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz"
                     ignoreExceptions="false">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="File-INFO"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="File-ERROR"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="File-DEBUG"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Test it:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(DemoApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        logger.error("this is an error");
        logger.warn("this is a warning");
        logger.info("this is an info");
        logger.debug("this is debug");
    }
}
```